# ActivityTypes.Typing clause gets executed in chatbot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am developing a chatbot using MicrofsoftBotFramework on c#.net and LUIS cognitive services.

I just want to know when ActivityTypes.Typing clause gets executed in below code , I want to see in my botemulator as "you are typing" when actually user is typing.

```
private async Task HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

            var reply = message.CreateReply();

            reply.Text = "Hello user how are you?"

            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

From the C# Bot Builder SDK Reference:

> Typing is an indicator of activity on the other side of the
>   conversation. Generally it's used by Bots to cover "dead air" while
>   the bot is fulfilling a request of some sort. The Bot may also receive
>   Typing messages from the user, for whatever purposes it might find
>   useful.

You can access that [reference page here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html#typing).

I hope this helps!